# MPMusicPlayerController deprecated with iOS 6

Tags: ios, mpmediaplayercontroller, ios6

I've just seen iOS 5.1 to iOS 6.0 API Differences released by Apple. They say that some important methods of `MPMusicPlayerController.h` are removed to `MPMediaPlayback` protocol (play, pause, stop...).

Does somebody know how to update my application who use the code below to work with the iOS 6?

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer play;
```

Comment: In the past, unreleased versions of iOS were under NDA...that is probably true with iOS 6, but I haven't looked to be sure.  You should probably ask this question on Apple's Developer Forums.

Comment: I think the dev-forums are down.

Comment: Thanks T Reddy, the Apple's Developer Forum is actually down, I will ask it when I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `MPMusicPlayerController` class conforms to the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol, and calling `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]` returns an instance of `MPMusicPlayerController`.  Moreover, all the deprecated methods that were removed from the `MPMusicPlayerController` class are present in the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol.  What this means is that:

1. No changes should be required for your code to work under iOS 6.  The `play` method still exists for every `MPMusicPlayerController` instance, and calling it should do the same thing that it always has.
2. No methods have actually been "removed".  They were moved into a protocol, presumably because having an abstraction of a media player API allows for very cool things to be done by providing custom object implementations that conform to the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol.